# D3 - Rotate text individually

Tags: d3.js

I have a plunker here - https://plnkr.co/edit/eh5DlisXGTqKt9bGtuMT?p=preview

I'm creating a stacked bar chart that will show a trend over months.

The months are on the x axis.

I want to show the type of each column with text underneath the column and rotated 90 degrees.

I have the text showing but if I try to rotate it, it rotates all the text as block and not each text individually.

How can I rotate each text block 90 degrees separatley.

```
this.layersBar.append('text')
  .text((d:any, i:any)=>{
    return d[i].data.type
  })
  .attr('x', (d:any, i:any)=>{
        return (i * this.width/this.data.length)+5;
    })
    .attr('y', this.height+15)
    .style('fill', 'black')
    .classed('trend-type', true)
    .style("text-anchor", "middle")
    .attr("transform", "rotate(-20)") 

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rotation is relative to an element's parent origin:

> the rotate is about the origin of the current user coordinate system.([source](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/coords.html))

unless specifying a rotational point. Since all your text shares the same coordinate system (that of the parent `g`), they all get rotated together, as a block as you note. And they are rotated around [0,0] of the parent `g`, not around their anchor or any point related to where the text lies.

Instead of appending text directly to the chart's `g`, you could append each label to its own `g`. If each of these `g` elements are transformed so that their origins correspond to text locations, rotation becomes easy.

Using your example, I append a `g` with a translate similar to where you position your  labels:

```
this.layersBar.append('g')
      .attr("transform",(d:any,i:any)=> {return "translate("+(i*this.width/this.data.length+5)+","+(this.height+35)+")"; })
```

Now I can append the text (no need to set x,y because 0,0 is now where I want the text):

```
this.layersBar.append('g')
  .attr("transform",(d:any,i:any)=> {return "translate("+(i*this.width/this.data.length+5)+","+(this.height+35)+")"; })
  .append("text")
  .text((d:any, i:any)=>{ return d[i].data.type })
  .style('fill', 'black')
  .classed('trend-type', true)
  .style("text-anchor", "middle")
  .attr("transform", "rotate(-20)");
```

Each label is now rotated around the origin of it's `g`, and each origin is positioned according to where the label should be:

[image]

Comment: Nice explanation ... helped me a lot.